# Rerun COPY instruction in main image Dockerfile to replace already existing same name file in base image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have an image that has Dockerfile with below instructions :-

```html
FROM openjdk:8-jre

VOLUME ["/hygieia/logs"]

RUN mkdir /hygieia/config

EXPOSE 8080

ENV PROP_FILE /hygieia/config/application.properties

WORKDIR /hygieia

COPY target/*.jar /hygieia
COPY docker/properties-builder.sh /hygieia/

CMD ./properties-builder.sh &&\
  java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar *.jar --spring.config.location=$PROP_FILE
```

Now i want to use it as base image and tag it as say something like hygieiaapi:latest and build a new image using it but overwriting the properties-builder file as a new instruction. Here is what i am trying to do :-

```html
FROM hygieiaapi:latest
COPY docker/properties-builder.sh /hygieia/
ENTRYPOINT ./properties-builder.sh &&\
  java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar *.jar --spring.config.location=$PROP_FILE
```

As such all i am trying to do is replace properties-builder.sh file under /hygieia directory with my new properties-builder.sh file and then use ENTRYPOINT to reset the CMD in base image. I'm not sure if the COPY instruction will be able to copy the properties-builder.sh file and replace that with already existing one (from base image) or will that conflict. I haven't built and tested this and want to seek clarifications first.
Please suggest.

Comment: Please try running your code and show any errors you've received.

Answer (score 0):

Can I know why do you want to replace the `properties-builder.sh`? I have managed to bring up this `hygieia` API image successfully using their default `dockerfile` & `property-builder.sh`.

If you want to change values inside the property file, you can just use environment variables instead for storing values. The properties-builder.sh checks for `env` values when creating the `application.properties` file.